# Why won't my jQuery work at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get jQuery to work on my page. so I used jsfiddle.net to test if my jQuery code works, and it does. However, when I copy and paste the same code unto my document, it doesn't work. So I'm assuming that there's an error with linking the jQuery external file on my html document. I'm using TextWrangler as my text editor.

html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Rules </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleRules.css"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript"  src="JsRules.js"> </script>
</head>
<div id="left" >
    <ol>
        <li> First Rule </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

css

```
#left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#left").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#left").fadeTo("fast", 0.25); });
});
```

Thanks for the time in answering and reading this. I'm currently stuck, I've reached a dead end, and I can't wait to overcome this problem!

Comment: Are you sure that `jQuery` is included in your code? Line `js/jquerry-1.10.2.min.js` seems to have a typo.

Comment: you seem to be typing `jquerry` everywhere instead of `jquery` - perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: jQuery has only one `r`.

Comment: if you use `chrome`, and use the console, these types of errors will be identified in the resources or console tab, as the resource `js/jquerry-1.10.2.min.js` will not be found.

Comment: Most browsers have JavaScript consoles which show up errors. You should read them before asking for help, and quote them if you don't understand them (after using a search engine, of course).

Comment: try this ofic resource ... http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: (I bet the issue is with a resource not found; this might not show up in the error console, but it *will* show up in the network resource console.)

Comment: It should still flag up a `$` undefined error.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate the fast responses! I changed the Jquerry to Jquery, but it still doesn't work. I'll try looking into the console to find the error.

Comment: Hmm...So I just ended up replacing <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquerry-1.10.2.min.js"></script> with 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
and it works fine now!
Again, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Go to your JS folder, click on the jquery file and drag it onto the html code and it will set the correct reference.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other people that it's most likely a typo in the name of your jQuery file.  I created a web page using your exact code except that I spelled the jquery file correctly.  It worked fine.

And even though using the BODY element is proper and important, it didn't affect the outcome of my testing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the "Inspect Element" (tools of chrome ) or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (tool of Firefox and Chrome) for find the error.

Now for me the possible errors are:

1. Name not declared correctly for example `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
2. you can change the script with external files ([libraries of google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)) `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>`

Now I create the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/38Cab/) on JSFIDDLE with your code and seems that it works

Answer (score -3):

You have a typo in your HTML referencing the jQuery document:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title> Rules </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleRules.css"  />
<!---Typo was here--->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
  <script type= "text/javascript"  src="JsRules.js"> </script>
</head>
<div id="left" >
        <ol>
            <li> First Rule </li>
        </ol>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Believe it or not, `<body>` is optional. You're wrong, BTW. `document` doesn't refer to `<body>`.

Comment: There is a body element in the HTML, it is just that the start and end tags for it are optional. You can still select it from the DOM event without the tags. `document` is the parent node of the HTML element anyway.

Comment: You are correct, I just realized that he had a typo like all the comments stated, haha. I'm a bit tired today.